# imac 2010 running xcode 5

Tags: ios7, xcode5

I know this is not a programming specific question, but I am wondering what are some of the issues that occur when upgrading and using xcode 5 on older iMac models(2010 to be more specific)? 
I know there are the obvious concerns of older components just running slower, and of course it would always be "best" to upgrade to a newer model, but I am wondering if it would be sufficient to just add RAM and other spec improvements as needed to develop iOS 7 mobile apps? (mobile app dev is really the primary purpose for using the mac)

Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade your RAM up to 16Gb and you'll be happy

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. Any idea on cost or other difficulties when upgrading RAM?

Answer (score 0):

Don't shell out for a new iMac, upgrade your RAM first, and if you have extra money and want to get dirty, upgrade to an SSD. Your iMac will be able to handle XCode no problems at all.

Comment: Awesome, that's what I like to hear. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I am running an 2.4 ghz I5 MacBook pro from mid 2010 with 8gb. No problems until now. Sure not my beloved machine but works ok. I cant upgrade higher then 8gb.